# I am a beginner getting an error trying to build functions

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a=4,b=8;
    float r=5.55;
    char c='comica';

    cout<<"this is a test and value of surtd is"<<a<<".\n and value of sturd is"<<b;
    cout<<"value of me is"<<'c';
    return 0;
}
```

I did all things as shown in a lecture, but it is showing an error in the compiler.

Comment: What error? Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  What compiler and version are you building that code with? [Edit] your post to include the actual error output you get from your compiler.

Comment: Are you sure about `return=0;`?

Comment: why does your char variable hold a string?

Comment: He is new here. Please be polite.

Comment: As it stands, the only diagnosable error in the posted code is the `return = 0`.  The other lines give warnings (if the compiler is suitable configured, and these might be treated as errors). However, the main problem is clearly that the OP has not interpreted lecture material correctly - in C++, careless use of single-quotes (`'`) and double-quotes (`"`) changes meaning of code. In one case single-quote is used where double-quote is probably intended, and in another case single quotes are used where they shouldn't be. So the OP needs to take more care in interpreting material from the lecture

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct `return 0` not `return=0` and also char should hold one char not string

Code should be

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a=4,b=8;
    float r=5.55;
    char c='c';

    cout<<"this is a test and value of surtd is"<<a<<".\n and value of sturd is"<<b;
    cout<<"value of me is"<<c;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`char` is used for storing single charecter. for storing a sequence of characters use `std::string` class.

```
string c = "comica"; 
//Note: Use double quotes for strings. single quotes are for charecter
```

Remove the quotes around variable `c`, Otherwise it'll print charecter `c` and not the value of string object `c`.

```
cout<<"value of me is"<<c;
```

as said in comments use `return 0`. `return=0` is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple mistakes in your code:

- Using a `char` variable initialized with a multi-byte character literal.
- Initializing a `float` variable with a `double` literal (and then not even using the variable afterwards).
- Passing a `'c'` character literal to `operator<<` instead of your `c` variable.
- Using a misplaced `-` in the `return` statement.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a = 4, b = 8;
    //float r = 5.55f;
    string s = "comica";

    cout << "this is a test and value of surtd is " << a << ".\n and value of sturd is " << b;
    cout << ".\n and value of me is " << s;
    return 0;
}
```